# complex number multiplication by a real number

Tags: complex-numbers, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

I'd like to multiply a complex value by a real integer. I know that multiplication of complex numbers is similar in the polar form, but the way I know and have been taught is to multiply the two real components then add the angles. What do I do when I have no angle and just a real number as the multiplier :

0.08∠76° ∙100

Best regards
Danny J

Comment: If you have a real number $a$, then you can treating the angle as $0 \ \text{rad}$: $a=a\cdot \text{cis}\ 0$.

Comment: 0.08∠76° ∙100=8∠76°  ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thanks how do I mark it as answered?

Comment: I've posted my answer as a real answer, so you should be able to mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have $0.08 \ \text{cis}\ 76^{\circ}$ and you want to multiply it by $100$. Just multiply the real number out from by $100$, so your answer is:

$$0.08 \ \text{cis}\ 76^{\circ} \cdot 100=8 \ \text{cis}\ 76^{\circ}$$